# My laptop is crashing througth renders, is my graphic card too old?

Tags: gpu

Hi (forgive my bad English), I have a HP Zbook i7, with a Nvidia Quadro K2100M. I use Blender (2.81) mainly to render clean mesh objects with some basic texture and hdri ligthing so I can have some reference for drawings and paintings. The last week I was working fine in Eeve and then redendering in Cycles (renders with low quantity of bounces and throwing to the GPU an "easy" render , optimizing here and there so I can have a quite noisy image but quickly and with enougth quality to work as reference and not as digital artwork). Today I added a few textures and now Blender is crashing while rendering. I dont know if it is doing to some bug or if indeed my graphic card is just not made for this, or if my laptop is having some actualization issues, I have tried to actualize or run old actualizations for a few hours, changing TDR values,  but I am done XD.

Any advice?

Comment: Lets say I need a new hardware, which low-mid budget laptop would you recomend? I don´t work large or medium scenes on Blender (is usually just an object as clean in mesh as I can with some ligthing, lets say a realistic car but without hard details on tires, relfections, I dont bother to textuer or model details that are not going to being visable on a painting,  neither run animations or hight resolution and photorealistic images). I have respect to the people who need or have fun with those features, I just dont need an ultraproffesional laptop for my needs I think

Comment: what is the crash report? render with cpu. if it's working you might be out of vram for the rendering that scene.

Comment: "A TDR has been detected.
The Application must close."Code: 7

Comment: I will try to render with CPU,

Comment: I would recommend cheapest laptop with more then 4gb vram but don't take my word for it. 4gb might work with you this year but some years later it might not because of updates or any other reason.
Also try AMD Radeon ProRender. And yes it works with nvidia and intel.

Comment: There is workaround for TDR in windows. most substance painter users even use it so it's common I guess. try googling "how to make TDR longer in windows registry"

Comment: I tried to make TDR longer already, didnt work, but CPU render did, was a long wait for a 2 sample render however. Thank you tho, you just avoided a panic and frustation-based credit cart purchase that I was just going to made lol XDDDD. I hope I can handle with this old friend (my laptop) one or two more months so I can  find one a little bit more expensive (still mid budget) but with a longer life

Comment: Thank you really, I still think my graphic card is failing, it worcked before yesterday. I have being changing setups for hours for renders taht made my laptop crash one time after antoher; with such frustation that I didnt think on deliver the work on the CPU (tunel vision). Now, I have been quitely standing the screen with so much peace T_T

Comment: np. If your cpu or gpu can handle open cl try it as well

Comment: Hardware questions are off-topic for this site and should be closed and posted to superuser.com.  The reasons being that we cannot reproduce or test the problem you are experiencing, the problem is highly specific to your system so unlikely to be helpful to others and finally being primarliy opinion-based it is not an answerable question.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour].  BTW blender 2.81 recommends a minimum of 4GB VRAM.